# OS X / cocoa - How get event on lock screen session

Tags: macos, cocoa, sandbox

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *jj;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize jj;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    [NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSEventMaskSwipe | NSEventMaskBeginGesture |  NSEventMaskGesture | NSEventMaskEndGesture handler:^(NSEvent *event) {

        NSLog(@"local");

        return event;
    }];

    [NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSEventMaskSwipe | NSEventMaskBeginGesture |     NSEventMaskGesture | NSEventMaskEndGesture handler:^(NSEvent *event) {

        NSLog(@"global");
    }];

    NSDistributedNotificationCenter* center;
    center = [NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

    [center addObserver:self selector:@selector(a) name:@"com.apple.screenIsLocked" object:nil];

    NSWindow* a = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] windows].firstObject;

    [a makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
    [a setLevel:kCGMaximumWindowLevel];
}

- (void)a {
    NSLog(@"sibar");

    [[NSApplication sharedApplication] activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];

    [NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSEventMaskSwipe | NSEventMaskBeginGesture |  NSEventMaskGesture | NSEventMaskEndGesture handler:^(NSEvent *event) {

        NSLog(@"local");

        return event;
    }];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}

@end
```

I want to get touch event when on lock screen

I want to develop custom lock screen

So I try to show screen over lock screen and get event

show screen is slove by
    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];

but event is not received

It is because window and app can't get focus

Please help me

// I will upload app on App Store, so I need non-sandbox-violance solution